# how to set line spacing for html <p>

Tags: html, css

For html `<p>...</p>`, how to set the line spacing using style sheet if the text for the paragraph have more then one line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
line-height: 1.5em;
```

Or you can use pixels:

```
line-height: 20px;
```